# WCF service contract and data contract

Tags: wcf, messagecontract, servicecontract

I have following code

```
  [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.myweb.com/prod")]
        public interface IBaseService
        {
    [OperationContract]
    public string GetName(IDMessageContract ID)
    }

    [ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.myweb.com/prod/child")]
        public interface IChildService : IBaseService
        {}

    public class BaseService 
        { public string GetName(IDMessageContract ID)}

    public class ChildService: IChildService 
        {}

    [MessageContract]
    public class IDMessageContract 
    {
      public string ID{get;set;}
    }
```

In above scenario I need the GetName method SOAP header containing the namespace "http://www.myweb.com/prod/child"

Comment: I want SOAP header containing namespace http://www.myweb.com/prod/child

Answer (score 0):

If you need SOAP header with specified namespace you must specify that header in message contract and use its Namespace property. Something like:

```
[MessageContract]
public class IDMessageContract 
{
  [MessageHeader(Namespace="http://www.myweb.com/prod/child")]
  public string MyHeader { get; set;}
  [MessageBodyMember]
  public string ID{get;set;}
}
```